# Allow only root and a certain AD domain group to access a certain server

Tags: active-directory, domain

I have configured a Linux server with PBIS-Open for AD authenticatie. I used the RequireMembershipOf command to add a allow a certain domain group to access the server. This is working great.
There is one problem: local Linux users are still allowed to login on the server, is there a way to allow only root and a certain domain group to the server?

**EDIT:**

I found it is possible to lock all local users with passwd -l except for root, so they are not able to login on the system. I don't know if this is a good way of solving the problem, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, I don't know if it is a good solution, but it seems to be working.

I use `passwd -l <user>` to lock the user account (except for the root account) so it's not possible to login with this user, but domain groups are still able to login.